# why to declare iboutlet for viewcontroller they are for buttons, slider, other controls etc

Tags: iphone, ios

`IBOutlets` are for `buttons, labels, images, slider, pickerview` and all other `controls` we drag n drop in our interface builder so we can connect them in our code but why to create `IBOutlets` of a `viewController` it do not make any sense. why `XCode` allow to create `IBOutlets` of a `viewController` its not a control dragged ad dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IBOutlet` flags a property as available for Interface Builder/Xcode to establish bindings to in a nib file. While they are normally used for binding instances of view objects within a nib that does not have to be the case. If you choose to you can load view controller instances or other objects from a nib and bind them to `IBOutlet` properties of other objects in the nib or the nib file's owner.